# YAML Ruby Load multiple environment variables

Tags: ruby, environment-variables, yaml, config, environment

I inherited a tool that is working correctly but when I try to extend it it just fails. Since I am new to ruby and yaml I dont really know what is the reason why this fails...

So I have a class config that looks like this

```
  class Configuration
    def self.[] key
      @@config[key]
    end

    def self.load name
      @@config = nil
      io = File.open( File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/../../../config/config.yml" )
      YAML::load_documents(io) { |doc| @@config = doc[name] }
      raise "Could not locate a configuration named \"#{name}\"" unless @@config
    end

    def self.[]=key, value
      @@config[key] = value
    end

  end
end

raise "Please set the A environment variable" unless ENV['A']
Helpers::Configuration.load(ENV['A'])

raise "Please set the D environment variable" unless ENV['D']
Helpers::Configuration.load(ENV['D'])

raise "Please set the P environment variable" unless ENV['P']
Helpers::Configuration.load(ENV['P'])
```

So I had a first version with the environment variable A that worked fine, then when I want to integrate 2 more environment variables it fails (they are different key/value sets). I did debug it and it looks like when it reads the second key/value it removes the other ones (such as reading the 3rd removes the previous 2, so I end up with @@config with only the 3rd key/value par instead of all the values I need).

It is probably easy to fix this, any idea how?

Thanks!

EDIT:
The config file use to look like:

```
Test:
  position_x: “56”
  position_y: “56”
```

Now I want to make it like

```
“x56”:
  position_x: “56”

“x15”:
  position_x: “15”

“y56”:
  position_y: “56”

“y15”:
  position_y: “15”
```

My idea is that I set them separately and I don’t need to create all the combinations…

Comment: Would you mind to share `config.yml` file? At first glance, it looks like you should  `@@config = YAML::load` instead of what you are doing there.

Comment: Sure I meant to do that forgot to include it. It use to be as simples as this:

Test:
  position_x: “56”
  position_y: “56”

Now I want to make it like

“x56”:
  position_x: “56”

“x15”:
  position_x: “15”

“y56”:
  position_y: “56”

“y15”:
  position_y: “15”

My idea is that I set them separately and I don’t need to create all the combinations…

Comment: Update your post, pls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time you call `load` you delete the previous configuration (in the line `@@config = nil`). If you want the configuration to be a merger of all files you will want to merge the new configuration to the existing configuration rather than overriding it.

Something like this:

```
def self.load name
  @@config ||= {}
  io = File.open( File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/../../../config/config.yml" )
  YAML::load_documents(io) do |doc| 
    raise "Could not locate a configuration named \"#{name}\"" unless doc[name]
    @@config.merge!(doc[name])
  end
end
```

Be aware that if the code was written as it has been because the method *was* called more than once, and the configuration *is expected* to reset between reads, you will need to explicitly reset the configuration now:

```
class Configuration

  # ...

  def reset_configuration
    @config = {}
  end
end

Helpers::Configuration.reset_configuration

raise "Please set the A environment variable" unless ENV['A']
Helpers::Configuration.load(ENV['A'])

raise "Please set the D environment variable" unless ENV['D']
Helpers::Configuration.load(ENV['D'])

raise "Please set the P environment variable" unless ENV['P']
Helpers::Configuration.load(ENV['P'])
```

Comment: Just perfect, thanks! I thought about that nill again, but even removing it I couldn't figure out how to merge them together! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I'd access the YAML using:

```
YAML::load_file(File.expand_path("../../../config/config.yml", File.dirname(__FILE__)))
```

`expand_path` cleans up the '..' chain and returns the cleaned-up version, relative to **FILE**. For instance:

```
foo = '/path/to/a/file'
File.expand_path("../config.yml", File.dirname(foo)) # => "/path/to/config.yml"
```

`load_file` reads and parses the entire file and returns it.